# Vector calculus notation

Tags: calculus, notation, vectors, matrix-calculus

Say we have a $n \times m$ matrix $\boldsymbol{X}$. When we see $\boldsymbol{X}^T_i$, is this typically referring to

(1) the i-th row of $\boldsymbol{X}^T$, which is a column vector. So $\boldsymbol{X}^T_i$ is $m \times 1$

(2) the i-th row of $\boldsymbol{X}$, which is a column vector, then take its transpose, giving us a row vector? So $\boldsymbol{X}^T_i$ is $1 \times n$.

I always get confused with notation in vector calculus. Is there a standard/popular usage?

Comment: I do not think this is a standardized notation. In fact, it would be most natural to me for this to refer to the transpose of matrix $X_i$, which would refer to one of a sequence of matrices $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ (for some index set $I$).

Answer (score 0):

I fully subscribe to davidlowryduda's comment. Thus, I would first specify that $X_i$ denotes the $i$-th column of $X$ and then, to avoid any ambiguity, I would write $(X^T)_i$ for (1) and $(X_i)^T$ for (2).

Comment: I had a typo in my OP. I actually meant the i-th row. Do you mean column or row?

Comment: This is why my answer starts by the sentence "I would first specify ..."

Comment: If you use $X_i$ to denote the $i$th *column* of $X$, then how do you denote a specified *row* of a matrix, and what symbol do you use for row index?